# Reading every char in a text file

Tags: java, text, bufferedreader, filereader

I'm attempting to read in every character (tabs, new lines) in a text file. I'm having some trouble reading all of these in. My current method reads the tabs in but not new lines. Here is the code:

```
//reads each character in as an integer value returns an arraylist with each value
    public static ArrayList<Integer> readFile(String file) {
        FileReader fr = null;
        ArrayList<Integer> chars = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //to be returned containing all commands in the file
        try {
            fr = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            int tempChar = ' ';
            String tempLine = "";
            while ((tempLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < tempLine.length(); i++) {
                    int tempIntValue = tempLine.charAt(i);
                    chars.add(tempIntValue);
                }
            }
            fr.close();
            br.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Missing file");
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Empty file");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return chars;
    }
```

I originally used the read() method instead of readLine() but that had the same problem. I'm representing the char as ints. Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Why not just manually add in newlines when you know that they would exist (IE, the current line has finished)?

Comment: It isn't feasible that `read()` had the same problem.  Why don't you use read(), and then ask about any different problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), `List` and the diamond operator `<>` and that you read each char with the [`BufferedReader.read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read%28%29) method.

```
public static List<Integer> readFile(String file) {
    List<Integer> chars = new ArrayList<>();
    try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);) {
        int ch;
        while ((ch = br.read()) != -1) {
            chars.add(ch);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Missing file");
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Empty file");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return chars;
}
```

The reason you aren't getting line endings is documented by the [`BufferedReader.readLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) Javadoc which says in part (emphasis added),

> A String containing the contents of the line, **not including any line-termination characters**...